# How to set graphics for just part of the screen? - Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, graphics, camera

I have a really peculiar question. I want to deteriorate the graphics in Unity **of just a part of the screen.** For example, if I'm playing a game with the screen split in two, one player can be playing with ultra graphics and the other, low ones. Is there a simple way of doing this, like setting the graphics quality on each camera? Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't imagine and easy way to do that.

Graphics are the conglomerate of multiple things (at least for me); the number of polygons of an object, the size of the textures, etc.

So the only thing I know you can do, is to duplicate the scene (like if you are making and on-line game) and load this duplicate scene with different materials, models and textures on one player scene. Then synchronize the rest of the scene, so both players are looking the "same" scene.

Also you can "deform" the image, with shaders or camera filters, like a Blurr effect! But this won't really affect the "graphics".

Comment: Not sure why you were downvoted. This answer answers the question and gives multiple alternatives to what was asked. It's a solid answer for such a broad question.

Comment: I don't know, I'm open to suggestions to improve it! ^^' But thanks @Ruzihm!

Answer (score -1):

I don't think that's currently possible. The game would have to render the same objects on 2 different ways, but that's just not possible in a good-performance scenario. You could very simple use prefabs with a lower quality on one of the screens or images with a lower resolution in the UI.

Do you really need this for your game? If u do some changes in the quality settings or change your game core mechanics, maybe the performance becomes good enough to skip this.